# Allow digits to be replaced in a length-limited field

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using a Regex to validate a number field. This allows only numbers in the field and the max length is 3 characters. Whenever there are 1 or 2 characters in the field and I select them by double clicking on them I am able to change the number by just pressing any other number.

However when the value contains 3 numbers, which is the max length of the field, when I select the number and try to input other number it doesn't work; I cannot input anything.

I thought this is an issue with the regex, but it's not. The issue is max length.
i tried changing max length whenever it hits the max length and I try to change it it doesn't work.

```js
// Restricting negative numbers and special characters from qyt field and maximum digits to 3
$('.js-bundle-qty').on('keypress', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode != 8) {
    console.log('demo');
    var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]{0,3}$");
    var inputValue = String.fromCharCode(!event.keyCode ? event.which : event.keyCode);
    var key = $(this).val();
    key = key + inputValue;
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
      console.log('enter');
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="js-bundle-qty" max="999">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sanket4real/310sgheL/30/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the field show only integers and then allow the next pressed integer to force the oldest character from the value, or be replaced by selecting them you can use a regex to replace non-digit characters and `slice()` within an `input` event handler, like this:

```js
$('.js-bundle-qty').on('input', function() {
  $(this).val((i, v) => v.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').slice(-3));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="js-bundle-qty" max="999" length="3" />
```

Comment: but this keeps taking numbers even after the length is reached. after reaching 3 numbers it replace first 3 numbers

Comment: That's right. To allow a number to be replaced you have to do it this way. The alternative is the logic you've got which requires the user to delete the number first.

Comment: in my solution do you think that is the expected behaviour. i think its right but the QA thinks that it should mimic the behavious of two numbers. when we select number and type anthing it should replace the value

Comment: update - i replaced .slice(-3) with .slice(0,3) , now it is working fine. Thanks for the help :)